# ADF - Run VSTest/MSTest/NunitTest as an activity in between pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

This is how my ADF looks like

Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3

All the activities are various transformation and data movements

My scenario is - I want to run VSTest/MSTest/NunitTest as an activity and run the next activity only of tests pass.

Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> run VSTest/MSTest/NunitTest -> If Pass -> Activity 3
-> If Fail -> Exit

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform these tests programmatically as there is no in-built activity/feature in ADF to do so.

What you can do is use the `if Condition` activity. Pass the next activity in True condition.

Refer: [If Condition in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity)